# In Qt: Can I output to `stdout`, as easy as I can output to `stderr` using qDebug()?

Tags: c++, qt, stdout, qdebug, qtextstream

Up until now, I output everything using `qDebug().noquote()`. This is easy because it just requires a simple `#import <QDebug>`

Now I need everything to output to `stdout`, but I don't know how to do it easily. This how I was taught:

```
QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
```

However, creating a new object is a tad bit more cumbersome than a simple `#import <QDebug>`. What is the good/least cumbersome way to handle `stdout` in qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is the one you mentioned. You don't have to create a new  local variable:

```
QTextStream(stdout) << "Hello world!" << Qt::endl;
```

If the source text is not Latin-1 encoded then you need to convert to `QString` before passing it to the stream operator:

```
QTextStream(stdout) << QString::fromUtf8("utf8 literal") << Qt::endl;
```

Comment: I'd accept this, but `QTextStream(stdout)` does not support unicode. Any way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not support unicode"? `QTextStream` converts from `QString` (UTF-16) to the default encoding for your locale (`QTextCodec::codecForLocale`) by default or any other encoding of your choosing (`QTextStream::setCodec`).

Comment: What I mean, is that my unicode is not displaying properly in my shell where as they would under `qDebug() << "≢≢≢";`

Comment: I suppose that the difference is that the `QTextStream::<<` overload that takes a `const char *` converts the input stream from Latin-1 while the `QDebug` overload must just pass that string straight through to the backend. So if your source file is UTF-8 encoded then you would have to use something like `QString::fromUtf8("utf8 text")` or just `QString("utf8 text")`.

Comment: Welp; any way around this?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter too soon. The workaround is to covert from your source encoding to `QString` before passing it to the stream operator. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @JasonHaslam this is where the `QString::fromXXX()` methods come in handy.

Comment: So if I use this everywhere I want output, it will instantiate a new QTextStream everytime, won't it?

Comment: @JohannesS. Yes

Answer (score 8):

`qDebug()`, `qInfo()`, etc. are all piped to a default message handler. But you can easily install your own that writes the debug strings to a different stream, file, or anything. All you need to do is define a message handler function and install it using [qInstallMessageHandler()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).

Putting it all together, here's a complete example:

```
#include <QDebug>

void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    cout << msg << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);

    qDebug().noquote() << "Hello world!";
}
```